# C++ Easily Cast Between Templated Pointer Types

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

Say I have a templated `Array<T>` struct and I want to cast from one pointer type of `T *` to another. Specifically, I have a function that returns an `Array<Entity *>` and I want to cast it to an `Array<Player *>`:

```
Array<Entity *> get_player_entities();

Array<Player *> players = (Array<Player *>)get_player_entities();
```

Note that `Player` extends `Entity`. Because pointers have the same size, this should be fine! But I get the following error:

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'Array<Entity *>' to 'Array<Player *>'; No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

So I can do the following, but it's a little bit cumbersome:

```
Array<Entity *> temp = get_player_entities();
Array<Player *> players = *(Array<Player *> *)&temp;
```

Wondering if there is an easier way to get around this? And why isn't this allowed? Shouldn't a cast of one pointer type to another always work? For example, in a non-templated world you can always cast between different pointer types.

Ideally, I would like the solution to not involve additional templating. For example, I know I could change the `get_player_entities` method to also be templated.

Comment: *Shouldn't a cast of one pointer type to another always work?*  Except for some kinds of edges cases (like casting member function pointers, or casting function pointers), usually casting one data pointer type to another pointer type either works, or it is undefined behavior.  The first case, the cast is not casting pointer types, so the question irrelevant.  The second case, it's undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Comment: Your bit-cumbersome solution is dreadful. If you're going to light up a new container holding transformed pointers, then do it with either a `std::transform` or similar. You're taking the hit of making a container copy anyway. Regarding your question, "Shouldn't a cast of one pointer type to another always work" No, it shouldn't, and it doesn't.

Comment: It's not about size; it's about semantics. A pointer-to-base has a different set of operations than a pointer-to-derived. There are situations in which an object of one of those types can be converted to the other, but there is no sledge-hammer to always force a conversion.

Comment: Since `Array` is your own type, you might consider adding a function to do the conversion: `template <class T> T* to_type(int idx) { return (T*)(*this)[index]); }`. You'd call it with an explicit type: `my_array.to_type<Player>(3);`.

Answer (score 0):

So down-casting is, in general, not safe. You could have `Foo` that also extends `Entity`, and casting all your `Entity` to `Player` with no checks will cause errors.

There are ways to do what you want (providing an explicit constructor to `Array<T>`, for example), but because you are dealing with pointers, I wouldn't advise this: you are dealing with raw pointers, it seems, so dealing with ownership and scope is going to be tricky. It is really hard to say how safe or dangerous this is without seeing what `Array<T>` is, and in the end, that looks like you're reimplementing part of the STL.

If you know that Array<`Entity`*> is really a list of Players, then use `Player` as the type, not `Entity`. If not, and you want to get the list of all players, the niave way would be to iterate all the Entity objects in the list, and then call `dynamic_cast<Player*>` on each pointer, putting that in a new `Array`. *That is usually a bad code smell and very expensive*. It means you've broken encapsulation - you should rethink the hierarchy of types and/or containers in your program.

Answer (score 0):

> Wondering if there is an easier way to get around this? And why isn't this allowed?

The general reason why `Array<Base>` is not convertible to `Array<Derived>` is that instantiating a template creates a *new* type. Two instantiations of the same template are two independent types. When we say `Array<Base>` (or whatever) we're no longer talking about a template called `Array`, but about a concrete type called `Array<Base>`.

Even if the template isn't specialized, many templates are so dependent on their type arguments that they change significantly depending on the type parameter used.

> Shouldn't a cast of one pointer type to another always work? For example, in a non-templated world you can always cast between different pointer types.

Sure, casting between `Entity*` and `Player*` works as normal. That's not at all what you're trying to do, though - you're trying to cast between the independent types `Array<Entity*>` and `Array<Player*>`.

There is a way to do what you want, but it's to write a wrapper type that does the pointer casting for you. Not to cast the top-level array object and force a copy.

Eg,

```
template <class Derived>
class ArrayView
{
    Array<Entity*> &data_;

public:
    explicit ArrayView(Array<Entity*> &origin) : data_(origin) {}

    Derived* front() { return static_cast<Derived*>(data_.front()); }
};
```

Finally, you'd end up with code like

```
ArrayView<Player> players{entities};
```

or whatever. Note that you need to be careful about the original array's lifetime, and that you need to replicate the whole interface with casts, etc. etc.
Oh, and you might want to use `std::is_base_of` or `std::is_convertible` or something to ensure you get useful errors if you make a mistake.